# How to get Base64-encoded token from paymentData?

Tags: android, token, payment, google-pay

According to the documentation, I have to send a Token received from Google Pay and encoded in Base64 in a POST request. But the bank responds with the error "Invalid value for the [paymentToken] parameter". How do i get this token?

```
//if you try it like this, then the answer is the same error.
PaymentMethodToken token = paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken();

//the same error
byte[] data = token.getBytes();
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Much of this depends on what the backend API on the bank's side is expecting. Banks usually provide a test or "playground" environment where you can test your code with values that are known to work... if you can, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

What payment provider/gateway are you using to process your payments?
Note that, to use Google Pay, you need to be working with one of the [supported processors](https://g.co/pay/processors).

Typically, it's most convenient to look at the integration details for your processor in their own docs. Control the body of your request and make sure that this is what your provider/processor expects.

Let us know how that goes.